# Google Maps stay on top

Tags: google-maps-navigation, maps

When Google Maps is in Navigation mode and I answer a call, the call gets brought to the foreground for the duration of the call. Wave has an option called "stay on top" that keeps the app in the foreground when you are answering a call.

Is such a feature available on Google Maps?

Note that all interaction with the phone is hands free and integrated to my car's multifunction steering wheel.

Comment: Do you happen to have a Lollipop device? See if you can work with screen pinning. It's not working for me but I haven't tried hands free either.

Comment: Assuming the 'answer call' function of your steering wheel is similar to the one that uses the button embedded in earphones, the pinned app option works. I tried it with my Nexus 5: if I pin an app and then receive a call the app stays on the screen but I can answer the call.

Comment: Screen pinning seems to be the solution. I learned something new today as I didn't know about this feature.